# HOWTO: get info from iTunes Distribution certificate and signing key (P12 file) and mobileprovision

Tags: openssl, itunes, pkcs#12, mobileprovision

When dealing with iTunes apps, the Distribution certificate and signing key (P12 file)and signing key (P12 file) and .mobileprovision (plist file) are a bit of a mystery to me.  I want to know how to get information from these files programmatically from the CLI.

How do you extract info from these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wildcard `.mobileprovision` file for the entire Dev center account. It contains:

- Distribution provisioning ID
- Company identity
- certificates

Each app that has push notifications enabled has its own `.mobileprovision` file (it contains the push cert and the wildcard cert).

The most useful command I have found is to convert the `.mobileprovision` file to XML, you can then do what you wish with it:

```
openssl smime -inform der -verify -noverify -in my.mobileprovision
```

The [CFPropertyList lib](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList) is a good PHP lib to interact with `.mobileprovision` files.

**The Distribution certificate and signing key** lives in a .p12 container.  As the name suggests it contains:

- Certificate
- App signing private key

Here are some handy commands:

To get when cert expires:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my.p12 -passin pass:1234 -nodes | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
```

To get the private key:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my.p12 -passin pass:1234 -nodes | awk '/-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----/,/-----END PRIVATE KEY-----/'
```

To get the cert:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my.p12 -passin pass:1234 -nodes | awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,----END CERTIFICATE-----'
```

Get the sha1 of othe cert:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my.p12 -passin pass:1234 -nodes |  openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint | cut -d "=" -f 2
```

Comment: How would I use OpenSSL to CREATE a .mobileprovision? Thanks in advance.

Comment: an iOS mobile provision can not be created by you. It is created by apple

Comment: Can I not use the "smime" command in OpenSSL to create one? I ask this because I do not want to pay $99 to get a .mobileprovision file just for testing.

Comment: Unfortunately every `.mobileprovision` file is signed by Apple's private key (namely, `Apple iPhone OS Provisioning Profile Signing` certificate). So only Apple can generate valid `.mobileprovision` profile.